# Where does keras actually initialize the dataset?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to figure out the implementation of SGD in tensorflow, especially how keras/tensorflow actually initializes and dispatches the dataset.

In the constructor (`__init__` method) of `class TensorLikeDataAdapter`, `self._dataset` is initialized by this [line](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/15d5b930d7e6e4463e275cfcff22042105148e3f/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py#L346)

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r2.5/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py#L346

```
self._dataset = dataset
```

I tried to print the value out with this line

```
print('enumerate_epochs self._dataset', list(self._dataset))
```

and I got

```
<_OptionsDataset shapes: ((None, 2), (None,)), types: (tf.float32, tf.float32)>
```

which seems to indicate that the dataset hasn't yet been actually loaded.

At the very begining of the [`enumerate_epochs` method](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/15d5b930d7e6e4463e275cfcff22042105148e3f/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py#L1196)

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r2.5/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py#L1196

I added this line

```
def enumerate_epochs(self):
    print('enumerate_epochs self._dataset', list(self._dataset))
```

and I got 3 (I set epoch=3) of the actual dataset, which means the dataset has been initialized and randomized somewhere before.

I went through the whole `data_adapter.py` but failed to locate where the dataset is actually initialized.

## highlight

I also tried this [line](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/15d5b930d7e6e4463e275cfcff22042105148e3f/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py#L1171)

```
  print('data_handler._dataset', data_handler._dataset)
  for epoch, iterator in data_handler.enumerate_epochs():
```

and I got

```
data_handler._dataset <_OptionsDataset shapes: ((None, 2), (None,)), types: (tf.float32, tf.float32)>
```

However, this [line](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/15d5b930d7e6e4463e275cfcff22042105148e3f/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py#L1209)

```
def _truncate_execution_to_epoch(self):
    print('_truncate_execution_to_epoch self._dataset', list(self._dataset))
```

gives 3 (epoch=3) of the actual dataset, which means somewhere **just in between** the dataset is actually initialized though I couldn't imagine where it could be!

I also tried [class DataHandler](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/15d5b930d7e6e4463e275cfcff22042105148e3f/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py#L1174)

```
print('DataHandler self._dataset', list(self._dataset))
self._configure_dataset_and_inferred_steps(strategy, x, steps_per_epoch,
                                           class_weight, distribute)
```

and I got this error

```
AttributeError: 'DataHandler' object has no attribute '_dataset'
```

Could someone help me to see the light at the end of the tunnel.

Comment: The function `enumerate_epochs(self)` is defined in the Class `class DataHandler(object)` at line 1095. Data Handler is an iterator over the Dataset for every epoch, that means the Dataset has to be initialized beforehand itself. I think the Dataset is initialized in the Class `class DatasetAdapter(DataAdapter):` at line 701 and specifically at line 718, I see `  self._dataset = x` after the `__init___()` .  This is what I think...I am also just curious!

Comment: Perhaps provide a minimal example demonstrating the usage of the dataset.